# Optimising REST API (python + sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, rest, optimization

Any suggestions on how to optimise this code? It works in a REST API but it's slow.

```
id = str(request.form['id'])
client = str(request.form['client'])
translationID = str(request.form['translationID'])

if os.path.isdir(id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (v1 TEXT, v2 TEXT, UNIQUE (v1) ON CONFLICT REPLACE )''')
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE v1=?', [st]):
        if(st == row[0]):
           return row[1], 200
return "", 404
```

Comment: How slow? Is it actually even possible to use `sqlite3.connect` with a directory?

Comment: It takes 3-4 seconds and I want to reduce this time as it slows down the process.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether the table exists or not in each request its much better if you could check this on server startup.

Secondly if you are developing a full fledged application i would highly recommend using ORM packages for this. I have worked on a flask project with raw queries and it becomes a tedious task to manage, validate, maintain, update, test and secure your code. It also lacks re-usability.

If you are new to flask following packages would be helpful:

1. **SQLAlchemy**: ORM for flask (https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
2. **Flask SQLAlchemy**: Flask extension for support of SQLAlchemy (https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)
3. **Flask Migrate**: Package for easy management of database migrations  (https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
4. **Flask Marshmallow**: For easy serializing and de-serializing of objects (https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

On the top of it you should go through this tutorial at least once https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world